# I need to transfer my website to another domain

Tags: wordpress, dns

I want to transfer my website from its domain to another domain that is used for my company emails.
The issue is that the first domain is not serving the website correctly, So I need to transfer the whole website to the company domain, But the company domain is used for important emails accounts (The email is like yamen@domain2.com), I'm not a network professional so if there any full solution description or a tutorial or just link that would be great.

I'm trying right now to backup my website to be ready for the transfer process.
But I do not know what is the best and healthy way to do that.
Is there any way to do that correctly with out losing any data (Because everything online).

Comment: First the emails have nothing to do with your website. You can either use migration plugin or in google "wordpress migration" with thousand of results and videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do a quick and secure backup and restore of all your site content, including the database, I use the "All-in-One WP Migration" plugin.
[All-in-One WP Migration](https://it.wordpress.org/plugins/all-in-one-wp-migration/)

It works very well

Comment: Thank you for the comment, But my main issue is with the transfer process, Is it ok to transfer to an email accounts domain without having a problem.

Comment: Can you explain more about that? What do you mean by transfer process?
once the site is transferred, from wordpress settings you can change email address.
 Thank you

Comment: Let's say I have a domain and I use it for email accounts only (No websites just email accounts have the form ' example@domain.com '), And I want to upload my website to the same domain, Is there any issue with that?

Comment: No, no problem, email and web space are 2 independent things